# Change series name in all charts on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through each chart on a single worksheet and rename the 3rd series:

```
With Sheets("Actual Traded Points")
    For Each Chart In .ChartObjects
        Chart.SeriesCollection(3).name = "Actual Traded Points"
    Next Chart
End With
```

But the Chart object doesn't seem to have a seriesCollection object and I cannot work out how to get to it. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually looping through the ChartObjects, not the Charts.  Try:

```
For Each co In .ChartObjects
    co.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).name = "Actual Traded Points"
Next co
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But what I do not understand is why I can't see the SeriesCollection object if I add co.Chart to the watch window and expand it?